# Drupal Console Running in Docroot

Tags: drupal-8

```
➜  docroot git:(master) ✗ drupal list
You must set up the project dependencies using `composer install`
```

I am trying to get the full list of commands for console and to do so I must run the console in the root of my Drupal site. However, when I type drupal list, I get the error above. Can someone tell me what this means? I did run composer install and I still get this error. Tried googling, no luck. I do have composer installed.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I am in docroot and am back to getting this warning:

```
[WARNING] In order to list all of the available commands you should install 
drupal first.
```

There seems to be a lot of this going around, according to Google and no one answer. Could be a bug. I do have a drupal site installed. I am using the Thunder Distro.